# kitchen-docker: How to run a shell command before kitchen converge

Tags: docker, chef-infra, test-kitchen

When using vagrant machines with test-kitchen the `pre_create_command` allows you to specify a command which is run locally before the vagrant machine is being created. With [kitchen-docker](https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-docker) no such configuration option seems to exist, and bending `chef_omnibus_url` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555280/how-to-run-shell-command-before-kitchen-converge-in-chef) isn't an option.

The script specified as `pre_create_command` for the testing vagrants generates a local chef data bag.

Is there a solution around which I've overlooked?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? (I.e: what this pre-provisioning command should do ?)

Comment: Just to repeat what Tensibai said, please add what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Best practices include Rakefile and Thor.

In essence you control your tests from a Rakefile. For example:

`rake style`

This will run all commands under your style task (maybe lint/syntax/unit and kitchen tests). Of course you can modify your tasks to perform whatever you like. Here are some good resources:

https://blog.chef.io/2015/04/21/overview-of-test-driven-infrastructure-with-chef/

See the Supporting Tools and Dependencies section.

Here is an example Rakefile:

https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/chef-server/blob/master/Rakefile

Comment: This isn't really related.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I don't think the answer fits my problem since I am talking of a singular kitchen test, not a complete test chain.

Comment: I do not know what your use case is, however, if you are trying to do some sort of logic PRIOR to the kitchen converge run a Rakefile works great. You do not need to run a 'suite' of tests. It can be simple a call to the shell script you described and a call to kitchen converge. Since it's just ruby/rake it's 100% flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I sketched a patch for kitchen-docker [here](https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-docker/pull/249/commits/1741e45011f14b7f8638b079f8fb643f0352232e). However, as the discussion on this pull request shows, there are arguments against an appropriate functionality in kitchen-docker, namely the one that such functionality (if ever) should go in the kitchen core.

So for the time being we have to live with this inconsistency between docker and vagrant, and this is where thun's answer comes into play.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using

```
driver_config:
  provision_command: <command>
```

in `kitchen.yml`

Check more [here](https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-docker#provision_command)

Kr,

Rshad